# node.js everyauth twitter mongodb error: You are trying to access the attribute/method configured by `findUserById`, which you did not configure?

Tags: node.js, everyauth

In the `findOrCreateUser` function, I'm returning a `promise`, that I then fulfill with a user document from mongoDB.

Then it gives this error `You are trying to access the attribute/method configured by findUserById, which you did not configure`

I used this guy's tutorial http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/26-starting-with-everyauth.html#video He didn't do any of that. Why does it even need a `findUserById` function? I'm returning to it the entire document, not just an id.

So, yeah, how do I correct this? I thought after you returned your `promise`, everyauth was good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if you have got around this or not, but I found adding in the following before you start telling it the api id's and secrets sorted it for me:

```
everyauth.everymodule
  .findUserById( function (id, callback) {
    callback(null, usersById[id]);
  });
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it needs a `findUserById` or what it does with it?

Comment: it uses that to make the user object available on req.user